# List of attributes on XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, attributes

I'm very new to Visual Studio for Mac.

In a project downloaded from internet, if I would like to change some object's attributes in XAML, the software shows a list of attributes like in the attached screen.

[image]

Anyway if I create a new project and I do the same thing, nothing appears like in the screen

[image]

As you can see, I write "ver" but nothing happens...
Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Hi, which version of Visual Studio for Mac ?

Comment: Using VB2019. Very strange behaviour, Intellisense works sometimes. I’m googling a little bit, a lot of people has this issue, but it seems there’s not a fix 

Comment: Yeah , I also get the phenemenon in visual studio for mac community.